# Is there maximum number of noise/ outliers in DBSCAN algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis, noise, outliers, dbscan

I did clustering on spatial datasets using DBSCAN algorithm and generating a lot of noise 193000 of 250000 data. is that a reasonable amount?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data and problem.

If I generate random coordinates, 100% noise would be appropriate because the data is random noise.

Answer (score 0):

First, to address the question in your title. By making `eps` 
very large, it is easy to get no noise points and all the points are 
in one big cluster. By making `eps` very small, you can easily 
make all points be noise points. In general, somewhere in between
is what you are looking for. Your job is to find a value that produces 
a *meaningful* clustering. That is where the remark of 
@Anony-Mousse comes into play.

> Depends on your data and problem

As he suggested, if you have *uniform* random data,  maybe all 
noise is the best answer. If you have *Gaussian* random data, 
maybe one big cluster with a few outliers is good. But this is 
supposed to help you understand the structure of *your* data.
What happens as you change eps?  From your current clustering 
with many noise points, what happens as you gradually increase `eps`?
Does it gradually add a few noise points into the existing clusters?
Is there some place where two clusters get merged into one? Is there 
someplace that there is a sudden change in the number of  clusters?
Also, can you interpret the clusters in terms of your variables? 
Perhaps the difference between two clusters is that in  one all the 
values of some variable are low and in another cluster they are high. Considering whatever problem you are trying to solve, 
do the clusters divide the data into meaningful groups? Try to use
the clusterings to find meaning in your data.